# Query result in Where clause in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, subquery, aggregate-functions

**Table**:

```
id  actor   result
1   Aman    20
2   Aman    23
3   Ston    21
4   halazon 21
5   klawi   20
6   halazon 14
```

I want to query actors by first letter and how many times they are in the table
I tried this but no success:

**Query**:

```
select actor, count(*) from actors 
where actor = (select actor from actors
where actor like 'A%' GROUP by actor order by actor ASC)
```

**Expected Result**:

```
Aman 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the point for a subquery - plus, it will fail if more than one actor has a name that starts with an A (the subquery will return more than one row, which cannot be used along with `=`).

If think you want direct filtering:

```
select actor, count(*) as cnt
from actors 
where actor like 'A%' 
group by actor 
order by actor
```

Comment: Anyway, if the subquery was necessary (in this case isn't: I totally agree with you but *if it was*) the correct operator would be `IN` and not `=`. Just writing this as a future reference.